# In WPF how do I reference and use a cs file from MainWindow.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, wpf, class

I am creating a WPF and I have also created a side menu for different processes I want to perform.  Currently all my code resides in the mainwindoe.xaml.cs.  I would like to break out my into seperate files.  For example menuitem1 code in one file, menuitem2 code in another file, etc.  I prefer this method as I feel it is cleaner and easier to maintain.  However I have tried doing Project-->Add Page-->Class but I don't know how to reference the code in the new page.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Kent

Comment: Without knowing the processes your want to perform, it becomes a question about the basics of coding. Dont know if this can be answered this easy. Maybe a suggestion for a good place to read about C# would be the better way: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/. According your question its the topic **encapsulation** http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_encapsulation.htm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can to put all files in the same or a abstraced namespace. And You have to work with classes in c#.

For example

- yourapp.mainwindoe
- yourapp.menuitem1
- yourapp.menuitem2

Addionally You have to set the classes You Need to Access from another Namespace to at least internal security Setting.

```
namespace yourapp.mainwindoe
{
    class YourClass
    {
        internal static YourMethod()
        {
           yourapp.menuitem1.YourOtherMethod();
        }
}

namespace yourapp.menuitem1 
{
    class YourClassOther
    {
        internal static YourOtherMethod()
        {
           // do something here...
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, in your class file you have the following:

```
namespace myNamespace
  {
      public class MyClass
        {
          public void MyMethod() { }
        }
  }
```

Let's assume that you have this in an assembly named MyDll.dll. You'd use it as follows:

1. You add a reference to `MyDll.dll` within the solution explorer
2. You include the namespace with using `myNamespace`;
3. Then you can use your class doing `MyClass test = new MyClass();`

If you don't add the namespace like Number 2., you'd use your class like:

```
myNamespace.MyClass test = new myNamespace.MyClass();
```

Comment: Hi @user6449566, do I need to create a .dll from my new class?

Comment: No this is just an example, just call it whatever name the class is!